# Qt libao undefined reference

Tags: c++, c, qt

I'm trying to get the libao library working in Qt. Here's what I have so far.

```
#include <ao/ao.h>
```

...

```
static int audio_driver;
static ao_device *audio_device;
static ao_sample_format audio_format;
```

...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ao_initialize();
    audio_driver = ao_default_driver_id();

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

It says that every reference to anything in the ao library is an undefined reference.

```
error: undefined reference to `ao_initialize'
error: undefined reference to `ao_default_driver_id'
```

And so on all the way through the code.

For what it's worth, every function in ao/ao.h is in an extern "C".

Any idea what's causing this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You doesn't link against ao dynamic library.

If you use qmake add following lines in `.pro` file

```
LIBS += -lao
```

If library in non-standard location, add these lines too

```
INCLUDEPATH += path/to/headers
LIBPATH += path/to/library
```

Comment: Thanks a lot- that really helped. I tried doing 'libao' and 'ao'. Guess that's why they didn't work. :P

Comment: As a side note, say I have libvorbis. -lvorbis again?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, or anywhere else where pkg-config is available, then the way this should be done is by adding "link_pkgconfig" to the CONFIG variable, and then add the package name to the PKGCONFIG variable. For example, if you're using libao and libvorbisfile:

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += ao vorbisfile
```

This will make sure that not only the correct link flags will be used, but also the correct CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS, which is also important.

Comment: Brilliant. The vorbisfile pkgconfig answered my next problem. Thanks a lot!